# Which types of Floor planes require to upload for Google indoor Application

Tags: google-maps, google-indoor-maps

I want to implement application for my building, where i would like to add functionality of google indoor maps.

I got some idea about how can i implement part of android application. But I am bit confused about floor planes of building. Because these floor planes should be uploaded on google maps through its website.

Which types of images are acceptable, it should be design by architect or shall we create in simple any application and upload?

Please clear my confusion so i can go ahead with it.

thanks & regards
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps accepts JPG, PNG, PDF, BMP, and GIF.
To see video on how to upload, you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR7lFsNFEjg). 
To upload, use this [link](https://maps.google.com/floorplans/find?hl=en).